# Perl open2() together with SIGCHLD, deadlock?

Tags: pipe, signals, freebsd, perl

From a Perl script on FreeBSD I open several child processes with `IPC::Open2::open2()`, passing to each process its "parameters" through its stdin (probably I should close stdin after this) and also I do:

```
sub handle_SIGCHLD {
  for(;;) {
    my $kid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG);
    break if $kid == 0;
    my $KidOutputFD = ...; # I stored the kid's output pipe FD earlier in the program
    my $KidOutput = read_file($KidOutputFD); # use File::Slurp
    # process $KidOutput
  }
}}

$SIG{'CHLD'} = \&handle_SIGCHLD;
```

Now the question: Can something in code like this cause a deadlock? I prefer to read the output of the kid not as it arrives, but when it terminates to read the entire output; may it cause problems?

Also the "parameters" I pass to a kid through stdin may be a long string. I am going to pass the entire string through one `print` operator with FD of the child stdin. Can it block in the middle of writing the parameters to the script?

What else should I do to be sure of no deadlocks? Maybe should I handle SIGPIPE? (I would not like to do it, too much work for simple transforming an input string into output string by a child process Is there a simpler way?)

Also note that I span multiple child processes. Sometimes I wait when a process terminates, sometimes I kill a child process with SIGTERM.

---

More specific question: May writing to a PIPE (which is opened at both sides and is not going to be closed) block (if the other side does not read it)?

Comment: `waitpid` can return -1, so that could put this code into an infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html (not FreeBSD, but I think this does not matter; after all there is the possibility that we may change our OS).

**Pipe capacity**
A pipe has a limited capacity.  If the pipe is full, then a write(2) will block or fail, depending on whether the O_NONBLOCK flag is set (see below).

Thus follows that the child process may "hang" attempting to write data to us and as a dealock we could infinitely wait when it terminates.

Answer (score 1):

> *May writing to a PIPE (which is opened at both sides and is not going to be closed) block (if the other side does not read it)?*

Most definitely. Pipes have a finite capacity, and writes to the pipe will block if the pipe is full.

For example, the following might happen in the child:

1. Writes to STDOUT
2. Writes to STDOUT
3. ...
4. Writes to STDOUT
5. Tries to write to STDOUT, but the pipe is full, so it blocks until the pipe is emptied some.

If this happens, the child will remain blocked indefinitely (and thus never exit) because the parent doesn't read from the pipe until the child exits. This isn't technically a [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) since the parent is still free to do whatever it wants, but it's definitely a problem.

Note: If the child makes the handle non-blocking, the write will fail instead of blocking.